# Using DbContext (net core) in Windows Service via external dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, windows-services

2 solutions in visual studio :

1 solution with 2 projects :

- library
- website ASP.NETCORE (api restful)

1 solution with 1 project :

- Windows Services

I've added the dll and Microsoft.AspNetCore + Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

In my Windows Service :

```
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FidelityContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=XXXXX;Database=XXXXXX;User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

        using (var context = new FidelityContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
```

Cause this error :

[image]

Log :

> - $exception         {"Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0,
>     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou une de ses
>     dépendances. La définition trouvée du manifeste de l'assembly ne
>     correspond pas à la référence de l'assembly. (Exception de HRESULT :
>     0x80131040)":"System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}
>     System.IO.FileLoadException
>
> === Informations d'état de liaison préalable ===
>
> JRN : DisplayName = System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>
> (Fully-specified)
>
> JRN : Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Xavier/documents/visual studio
>   2017/Projects/SocietyServices/SocietyServices/bin/Debug/
>
> JRN : PrivatePath initial = NULL
>
> Assembly appelant : Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null.
>
> ===
>
> JRN : cette liaison démarre dans le contexte de chargement de default.
>
> JRN : utilisation du fichier de configuration de l'application :
>   C:\Users\Xavier\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\SocietyServices\SocietyServices\bin\Debug\SocietyServices.exe.Config
>
> JRN : utilisation du fichier de configuration d'hôte :
>
> JRN : utilisation du fichier de configuration de l'ordinateur à partir
>   de
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>
> JRN : référence post-stratégie : System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>
> JRN : tentative de téléchargement de la nouvelle URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Xavier/documents/visual studio
>   2017/Projects/SocietyServices/SocietyServices/bin/Debug/System.Runtime.DLL.
>
> AVT : la comparaison du nom de l'assembly a entraîné l'incompatibilité
>   : Version secondaire
>
> ERR : impossible de terminer l'installation de l'assembly (hr =
>   0x80131040). Détection terminée.
>
> Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou
>   une de ses dépendances. La définition trouvée du manifeste de
>   l'assembly ne correspond pas à la référence de l'assembly. (Exception
>   de HRESULT : 0x80131040)
>
> à System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig,
>   RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
>
> à System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
>
> à System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()
>
> à System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParametersNoCopy()
>
> à System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()
>
> à
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbSetFinder.<>c.b__2_0(PropertyInfo
>   p)
>
> à System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext()
>
> à System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> à System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.d__1.MoveNext()
>
> à System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
> à System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> à System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> à Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbSetFinder.FindSets(Type
>   contextType)
>
> à
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>
> à
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbSetFinder.FindSets(DbContext
>   context)
>
> à
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbSetInitializer.InitializeSets(DbContext
>   context)
>
> à Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions
>   options)
>
> à
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext`3..ctor(DbContextOptions
>   options)
>
> à API360Plus.Model.Data.FidelityContext..ctor(DbContextOptions`1
>   options) dans
>   C:\Users\Xavier\Source\Workspaces\API3605\Main\Core\Model\Data\FidelityContext.cs:ligne
>   64
>
> à SocietyServices.Society_GenerationAnniversaire.Traitement() dans
>   C:\Users\Xavier\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\SocietyServices\SocietyServices\Society_GenerationAnniversaire.cs:ligne
>   90
>
> à SocietyServices.Society_GenerationAnniversaire.T1_Elapsed(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) dans C:\Users\Xavier\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\SocietyServices\SocietyServices\Society_GenerationAnniversaire.cs:ligne
>   152
>
> à System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my answer, it's because my library is in net core and not in net standard.
Now its work perfectly !